# index.php not displaying when navigating to directory with iis6

Tags: php, iis

Found that IIS was looking for `iistart.htm` before looking for `index.php`!

---

I am building an application on a iis 6 server and I am running into a problem. When I type in `http://server/index.php`, I find my page fine. If I remove the `index.php` I lose the page. It is directly on my root, and I am accessing my root with `http://server/`.

I originally thought I had messed up with the web directories in the iis settings, but I tested it on a folder one directory deep, example: `http://server/folder`. This brought up the index.php webpage in that browser and I didn't need to add `index.php` at the end.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to configure IIS to use index.php as a directory index page, and raise it in the order of priorities.  It seems you have another index.html file, and index.html is probably farther up on the list than index.php.

1. IIS Manager->Web Sites
2. Right-click your site and hit properties
3. Documents Tab
4. Click index.php and move it to the top of the list.

Comment: But when I place `index.php` in a directory below, it reads the `index.php` first thing. Example: `http://server/folder` picks up the `index.php`

Comment: @Phil, you can set these settings differently for each directory.  If you set them on the root site, it will prompt you to overwrite any sub-directory settings that are different.

Comment: Ahh, okay, let me try that out.

Comment: That worked! Yay! Thank you very much. Apparently it was reading `iisstart.html` before the `index.php`!